# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, AccountNumber reqvired

Tags: salesforcedx

There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, AccountNumber reqvired: []

For this I have cheeked with validation rules on account and contact and I deleted validation rules but no use . Again I am getting the same error.

Comment: are you sure... there is a tipo here (reqvired) or you typed it wrongly?

Comment: Check Account trigger. Validation can be fired from trigger also using addError.

Comment: also it is seeing Custom Validation, so... or it is a validation rule or it is a trigger